# What are all available Git special files that can be committed to a repository?

Tags: git

Two examples I can think of are `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore`.

Can someone list all of them?

Comment: Another special file: `.gitmodules`

Comment: I don't know if its an official dotfile but I use `.keep` in empty directories so that an empty folder is included in my repository

Comment: @Parham, the usual practice is to use an empty .gitignore file for that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I grepped the git repository of git itself, and while I don't think an official list exists anywhere, I did notice that all the ones I know about were mentioned in the git-config manpage (`git help config`).  So with that, I did a search for "file" on that page, and here's what I found:

- [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) - List of blobs for git to ignore.  Affects commands like `git add` and `git clean`.
- [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) - Let's you define attributes on files (e.g., to change how files look in a diff).
- [`.mailmap`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap) - Lets you tell git that duplicate names or emails in the history are actually the same person.  Affects commmands like `git shortlog -ns`, or `git log --format="%aN <%aE>"`.
- [`.gitmodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules) - Let's you define submodules (subdirectories of your git repository which are checkouts of other git repositories).
- `*.keep` - Something to do with making `git gc` ignore packs. I couldn't find much info on this, so I'm not even sure if it's a file that you commit to the repository or just something that lives in `.git`.  If someone knows more please comment.

That's all I found.  I hope I didn't miss anything.

Comment: I believe `.gitkeep` is generally used to commit and push an empty folder onto your git repository.

Comment: `.gitkeep`/`.keep` files aren't handled in any special way by Git, they are just a convention used by many projects - a file with a name like this can be added to directories that would otherwise be empty, and this way these directories will exist as soon as the repo is cloned, without needing to be created by some other script or the user manually. This is useful as Git will not track empty directories in a repo, so creating a placeholder file is necessary to do this.