# commit git branch to SVN

Tags: git, svn

We are using SVN in our project. I customized an open source project which is hosted in GitHub. I checked out the source code for the third party library from GIT and made some modifications.

Now I need to commit my files to our local SVN repository.

How can I commit the project to my local SVN ignoring the git related changes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> How can I commit the project to my local SVN ignoring the git related changes.

If you mean committing the modified files without the git files, then excluding `.git` directory and `.gitignore` file in the root of the project would do the trick most of the time. For full list of git special files you might refer to [What are all available Git special files that can be committed to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605576/what-are-all-available-git-special-files-that-can-be-commited-to-a-repository)